# ?? operator seems not to work -> enclose the ?? evaluation part with brackets

Tags: c#, .net, operators

Recently I spent some time to find a tricky behaviour, I did something like this

```
public static string GetPrefixedNameList(string[] names, string prefix = null)
{
    if (names == null || names.Length == 0)
        return "";
    return prefix ?? string.Empty + string.Join(", ", names);
}
```

very easy, I quess
but I always got the prefix only or an empty string as result, but never a joined name list

to make it working correctly:
**always enclose the "?? evaluation part" with brackets when it is an intermediate result!!**

```
return (prefix ?? string.Empty) + string.Join(", ", names);
```

VS2012: no warning, no hint, the joining name part was simply ignored!!!
this seems to be a compiler error!!!

It's not realy a question, may be someone else can save some time

Answer (score 2):

> VS2012: no warning, no hint, the joining name part was simply ignored!!! this seems to be a compiler error!!!

No, it's really not. It's just a matter of precedence. `+` binds tighter than `??`.

You've written entirely legal C# - it just doesn't do what you expect it to. Your code is equivalent to:

```
return prefix ?? (string.Empty + string.Join(", ", names));
```

Personally I would rewrite the code as:

```
prefix = prefix ?? string.Empty;
return prefix + string.Join(", ", names);
```

EDIT: As Marc says, you don't even need to do *anything* here - because `null` ends up as an empty string in concatenation, so you only need:

```
return prefix + string.Join(", ", names);
```

I note that you drop the prefix if `names` is empty or `null`, by the way - is that deliberate? Also, I'd suggest that you should be consistent between *either* using `""` *or* using `string.Empty`. Personally I use `""`, but that's a matter of taste. Consistency reduces surprise though :)

See section 7.3.1 of the C# 5 specification for a list of the precedence of the various operators etc in C#.

Comment: Actually, because string concatenates null-strings perfectly happily, you don't even need to worry about the null in the first place

Answer (score 1):

The compiler also doesn't provide warnings or hints if you do:

```
var d = a + b * c;
```

when you meant:

```
var d = (a + b) * c;
```

In both cases this is just operator precedence. This is not an error.

As for "name part was simply ignored" - no; if `prefix` had been `null`, the right hand side would have been evaluated (as per the rules for the `??` operator). The important thing to realize in your specific scenario is that *without* the parentheses your expression is effectively:

```
return prefix ?? (string.Empty + string.Join(", ", names));
```

Personally, I don't recommend learning operator precedence rules: if in doubt. ***add more parantheses***:

```
return (prefix ?? "") + string.Join(", ", names);
```

however, string concatenation with null *ignores the null*, so the following is fine:

```
return prefix + string.Join(", ", names);
```